# Post status to Facebook using Django and django-facebook package

Tags: python, django, django-facebook

I installed django-Facebook and Django-registration. Django-registration is working fine but django-Facebook is not.I need to post status to Facebook via textarea provided in my site. As i am newbie to Django, a clear and step-by-step guide would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is using 2 different backends, django-registration and django-facebook, in this case I prefer using the facebook API.

Comment: Step-by-step: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/facebook-connect-with-django/